# "Shift+R improves the quality of this image. Shift+A improves the quality of all images on this page."

Tags: browser, isp

When surfing and hovering over any image on a page I get a box: *"<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> improves the quality of this image. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> improves the quality of all images on this page."* This happens on every image on every page & the box covers most of the picture.

I have a Lenovo laptop, Windows 7, 64 bit & I use Chrome as my browser. I use my HTC Desire as a **Wi-Fi Hotspot** with **Cricket** as my carrier.

On another forum there was quite a discussion about people having the same problem, and a guy came up with a solution, but nowhere does he say where to insert it.  The person he was helping used **Firefox** and **Virgin** was his carrier.  The problem was found in JavaScript and the man that fixed it said here is the solution to the problem for ALL browsers and carriers:  `http://1.2.3.4/bmi-int-js/bmi.js`   Somehow I found JavaScript with this in the body on a Craigslist posting...

But now what to do with it?  I beg for anyone's help, as this has been driving me crazy since I bought my laptop in January.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Vodafone's mobile internet via my laptop. If I use the software from Lenovo to connect I can enable/disable the compression of the webstreams.

Generally it is a feature that saves bandwidth/costs.

**The compression is done by the carrier** so you can ask them do disable it or check the settings of your Modem Device (HTC Desire) if you can disable it there.

If nothing helps you can try to use a VPN- or Socks-connection over SSH. The idea is to encrypt the webstream so your carrier does not have the possibility to change it before sending it to you.